# How can I use Python to stream multiple audio files simultaneously

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, stream, raspberry-pi

I’m looking to stream multiple audio files in .wav format to a Raspberry Pi for synchronous playback. I’m looking to use Python as my language of choice and TCP sockets, although I understand UDP might be necessary for latency. Anyone who can point me in the right direction/give some input would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is a question that will get opinionated answers. Next time reword your question to be similar to "how can I use python to stream audio files?"

Comment: My bad, just edited now

Comment: Anyone at all...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there are many approaches to do such a thing. For example, you can write your own Python script and send audio frames on a socket. But if you just need to do a stream you can use high-level tools like [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/). It will give you a bunch of solutions to stream your Audio and Video on the network with bare UDP or well-optimized protocols like RTP or RTSP.

For example, if you want to stream the ALSA device `plughw:1,0` to your localhost, it would become something like this:

```
ffmpeg -ac 1 -f alsa -i hw:0,0 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32k -ac 1 -re -f rtp rtp://localhost:1234
```

Also, you can use other tools like Alsa recording app (`arecord`) and pipe its output to FFmpeg:

```
arecord -f cd -D plughw:1,0 | ffmpeg -i - -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32k -ac 1 -re -f rtp rtp://localhost:1234
```

Then you can simply play it with `ffplay`:

```
ffplay rtp://localhost:1234
```

You can find more info about FFmpeg's streaming feature in [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide).